# Displaying embeded image as background

Tags: media, views, nodes

I would like to allow users on my site to be able to display a background image, not from their computer but from an outside source, for their profile page.

I assume the best way to do this is to add some kind of an image embed field on the front end of the profile page and tweak the CSS so that the image resides in the background (panel.)

If so, my question is twofold: (1) What is the best module to use to link to the image and, (2) how do I display the field to users? Do I create a content type and use exposed filters in views to display it?

Is there a better approach?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Background Images module](https://drupal.org/project/bg_image) as a ready-built solution:

> Background images is a collection of modules that allows users to add
>   background images to html elements on pages of the site

Comment: It looks exactly like what I am looking for. Thanks so much. :)